# Get error from hibernate validator and bind it to Swing

Tags: java

i had made rich application. And i'm using hibernate validator as my validator. Emm i have question , about how to get error message from hibernate validator and bind it to my swing. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you get the error message and display it on the Swing UI as a lable?

[ConstraintViolation.getMessage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html#getMessage%28%29)

Comment: Follow this tutorial for examples: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/

Answer (score 0):

Use message field of annotation to provide messages as keys from properties file.

Suppose properties file contains below

> test.username.empty = Incorrect username provided.

Then you can provide

```
 @NotNull(message="test.username.empty")
 private String username
```

Now you can collect all messages look-up from properties file and display them